# Is there a way to configure yui compressor to obfuscate javascript in Rails >= 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, yui-compressor

There is an existing `munge` option in JavascriptCompressor which is part of the Yui Compressor. Is there a way to pass custom settings to this compressor when configuring asset pipeline in Rails >= 3.1 app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easy way to do this. In your `config/production.rb` you need to set up YUI compressor with munge option:

```
config.assets.js_compressor  = YUI::JavaScriptCompressor.new(munge: true)
```

Make sure you have compression enabled in the same file:

```
config.assets.compress = true
```

And also clean all cached files after enabling this in `tmp/cache/assets` and `public/assets`.